# Can I recover data from deleted hard drive partitions on a Windows 95-98 PC?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, fdisk, windows-98, windows-95

I have some old Windows 95-98 era PCs that I would like to recover data from if possible. They have all had the hard drive partitions deleted using 'fdisk' and have not been used since. Would it be possible to recover any data and, if so, what would be the safest ways to go about attempting this?

Comment: this question has been ask about a gazillions times... please do some research before you ask. **IMPORTANT:** And make an image of the HD before you try to recover the partition.

Comment: Probably the best software for that and its free>>>>https://downloads.tomsguide.com/GetDataBack-For-FAT,0301-33753.html